# Win32 API calls throwing access violation

Tags: c++, winapi, encoding

I've got a simple piece of C++ code I'm exporting from a DLL.

```
DWORD WINAPI MessageBoxThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    MessageBox(0, L"Test", L"Test", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's how I'm calling it

```
typedef DWORD(*MessageBoxThread)(LPVOID);
int StartMessageBoxThread() {
    MessageBoxThread ShowMessageBox;
    HMODULE testModule = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Users\\david\\COMServer.dll");
    ShowMessageBox = (MessageBoxThread)GetProcAddress(testModule, "MessageBoxThread");
    ShowMessageBox(NULL);
    FreeLibrary(testModule);
    return 0;
}
```

I get an exception thrown in KernelBase.dll on the ShowMessageBox() line, involved an access violation when writing to a memory location.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Both Visual Studio projects are set to Unicode, and I know using the L prefix denotes wide strings.

I can debug and step through into my DLL, I see the address of my function, so I can't see anything wrong with the code calling the function.

Comment: Did you disable name mangling for the DLL export? I suspect your `GetProcAddress` call is failing but since you're not checking for errors you have no way of knowing.

Comment: You should also check for the return value of `LoadLibrary`

Comment: @JonathanPotter I am using a def file, so no mangling

Comment: @Mirko I took that out for brevity, but GetLastError() is returning 0 for both calls

Comment: Don't remove error checking code. We need to see that too. For all we know you are doing it wrong. Indeed if you don't check return values you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `StartMessageBoxThread()` code, `MessageBoxThread` is declared incorrectly. Specifically, it is missing a calling convention, so it uses the compiler's default convention, which is typically `__cdecl` rather than `__stdcall` (what `WINAPI` maps to). Calling convention mismatches are a common cause of crashes, call stack corruption, etc.

Also, the code has no error checking at all.

Try this instead:

```c
typedef DWORD (WINAPI *MessageBoxThread)(LPVOID);

int StartMessageBoxThread()
{
    HMODULE testModule = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Users\\david\\COMServer.dll");
    if (testModule)
    {
        MessageBoxThread ShowMessageBox = (MessageBoxThread) GetProcAddress(testModule, "MessageBoxThread");
        if (ShowMessageBox)
            ShowMessageBox(NULL);
        FreeLibrary(testModule);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
typedef DWORD(*MessageBoxThread)(LPVOID);
```

The prototype does not match the definition in dll. By default calling convention here is `__cdecl` whereas `WINAPI` is `__stdcall`

```
typedef DWORD(WINAPI *MessageBoxThread)(LPVOID);
```

Specifically, at the called end, since the convention is `__stdcall`(callee clears the stack), the function pops argument off the stack. At the caller end, it sees that the convention is `__cdecl`(caller clears the stack) and it also pops the argument from the stack, eventually corrupting the stack.